# Alternatives to PRISM

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I am starting a large Enterprise level Silverlight Application, and i am not looking at PRISM since i would not be using many of its capabilities. But i intend to design the application modular and use MVVM. What are my best alternatives to PRISM? Thanks.

Comment: MEF,Unity,Ninject .. ect , they all are DI (IoC), non of them are suppose to do what PRISM dose? so better to find something else, PRISM is good but i need some more secure in loading modules,so that it could load only specialty signed modules. any idea ?

Comment: This might help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005356/alternatives-to-prism-mef-for-modular-mvvm-apps

Answer (score 2):

A good reference is: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/IssueVisionForSilverlight.aspx

Answer (score 1):

MEF + MVVMLight